t letter before every item of listofexercises and error on compilation
I have the letter t appearing at the beginning of each line of my exercise list.
I've found a way to remove it on this page, but when I compile I get the following error message
Undefined control sequence.
l.33 \patchcmd
              {\@@@ExeEnv}
/home/name/Desktop/.tmp.tex.swp:33:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output P
DF file produced!

My "texlive-latex-extra" package is up to date. However, when I use the overleaf website, everything works. I don't understand...
could you please help me ?
here is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\hypersetup{
bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
pdffitwindow=true,      % page fit to window when opened
pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
urlcolor=vert           % color of external links
}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\disp}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}

\usepackage{exercise}
\makeatletter
% remove the faulty \expandafter
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeEnv}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@ExeCmd}
  {\theExercise\ \expandafter}
  {\theExercise\ }
  {}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\listofexercises


\begin{Exercise}[title={Probabilité que deux entiers soient premiers entre eux}, difficulty={3}]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Soit $n\geqslant1$. Si on note $r_n$ la probabilité que deux entiers choisis aléatoirement dans $\llbracket1, n\rrbracket$ soient premiers entre eux, alors $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}r_n = \dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$.
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[title={Théorème d'approximation de Weierstrass }, difficulty={2}]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Toute fonction $f\in\mathscr{C}^0([0,1],\R)$ est limite uniforme d'une suite de fonctions polynômiales.
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[title={Irrationnalité de $\pi$}, difficulty={2}]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
On pose, pour tout $n\in\N$, $\disp I_n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right)^n\cos(x)\dx$.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Montrer que $I_n$ est un polynôme en $\pi$ à coefficients entiers.
\item En déduire que $\pi\not\in\Q$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\end{Exercise}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

As long as there is an error, no need to worry about any strange t's appearing in your document. After an error, latex only recovers enough to to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

you need \usepackage{etoolbox}, which provides the \patchcmd command

Off-topic: top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm may be expressed more succinctlty as margin=3cm.

Are you sure exercise wants to be loaded after hyperref?

On MacTeX2024, I am unable to reproduce the undesirable behavior you say you're encountering.

thank you for your answers.
Robert, I added the \usepackage{etoolbox} package and it works fine now, thank you very much!
